# Is there a way to edit a decision split configuration in a running journey?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, journeybuilder

I would like to add additional criteria in the decision split. However, the journey is currently running and will only end in another 10 days. Is it possible for me to edit it? What is the best possible way to edit the decision split and at the same time, resume the journey activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only edit journey paths by publishing a new journey version. This will not have effect on contacts currently in journey, but the contacts who are injected after your new version goes live will follow the path with updated decision split.

Comment: Sad it's 2022 and this is still the case.